# Constructing Taylor series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

I am having trouble constructing the answer to this problem, which is also linked here: [Convergence Properties of the Taylor Series for $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167106/convergence-properties-of-the-taylor-series-for-frac1z1-z).

> Find and state the convergence properties of the Taylor series for the following:
>   $$\frac{1+z}{1-z}$$
>   around $z_0=i$.

When I construct it, by taking the derivative of $f(z)$ and evaluating it at z=i, I get $\frac{2j!}{(1-i)^j}$, leading to: $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(1-i)^{j}}(z-i)^j$$ then by re-indexing, I get:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(1-i)^{j+1}}(z-i)^{j+1}$$but that isn't the answer. Why is the answer of the form: $$i+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(1-i)^{j+1}}(z-i)^j?$$

Comment: "Taking the derivative of $f(z)=i$"? No, take the derivative of $f(z)$, and evaluate it at $z=i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using geometric series:
In general we have the formula:
$$
\frac{1}{a-x}=\frac 1a\frac{1}{1-(x/a)} = \frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{a^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{a^{n+1}}.
$$
To apply it here we use 
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1+z}{1-z}&=\frac{1+i+(z-i)}{1-i -(z-i)}\\
&=(1+i + (z-i))\frac{1}{(1-i)-(z-i)}\\
&= (1+i + (z-i))\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^n}{(1-i)^{n+1}}\\
& = \cdots
\end{split}
$$
(Note that expanding around $z_0=i$ means that the series should be in terms of $(z-i)$.)

**Edit**: We continue 
$$
\begin{split}
\cdots&=  \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1+i)\frac{(z-i)^n}{(1-i)^{n+1}} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^{n+1}}{(1-i)^{n+1}}\\
& = \frac{1+i}{1-i} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1+i)\frac{(z-i)^n}{(1-i)^{n+1}}+\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^{m}}{(1-i)^{m}}=\cdots
\end{split}
$$
Noting that $1+i=i(1-i)$ gives
$$
\begin{split}
\cdots&=  i + \sum_{n=1}^\infty i\frac{(z-i)^n}{(1-i)^{n}}+\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^{m}}{(1-i)^{m}}\\
&=i+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^n}{(1-i)^{n}} (1+i)\\
&=i+\sum_{n=1}^\infty i\frac{(z-i)^n}{(1-i)^{n-1}}. 
\end{split}
$$
I hope I haven't made any calculation mistakes.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that neat trick! But if I wanted to do it my way how can I construct it. What did I do wrong?

Comment: And also, what I am having difficulty is reindexing the summation. How will I be able to reindex the last equation:$$(1+i + (z-i))\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^n}{(1-i)^{n+1}}?$$

Comment: I added the full derivation of the series.

Comment: Regarding the correctness of your construction, I find it hard to derive the function $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ at $z=i$, when I can just use geometric series, so I can't say if you are right or wrong. But the answers differ, so either you are correct, or me, one can check...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what is

$$\frac{1+i}{1-i}$$

This is the coefficient of $(z-i)^0$ in your expansion.

Comment: Hmm, I do not know?

Comment: You can show that it is equal to $i$.

Comment: Oh I see now. But I am still a bit confused on how to get/construct the correct series equation.

Comment: You already did above; you were just missing the $(z-i)^0$ piece.

Comment: The answer is: $$i+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(1-i)^{j+1}}(z-i)^j?$$ which I know is right but I don't know how to reindex correctly. For ex. how did the OP know to put $i+$ before the summation?

Comment: Because the Taylor series about $z=i$ is given by $$f(i) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}}{k!} (z-i)^k$$.  Again, the derivatives have been computed, and that just left the zeroth-order term.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel dumb now thanks a lot!